# python - get target line in a file etc. then get a specific previous line?

Tags: python, string, enumerate, readlines

I need to find a certain line in some output. I can do this, but then having found the right part of the output, I need to extract certain lines before that one.

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
 target = str(self.ma3) # set target string
 if target in line:
  print i, line     # this gets the correct line, I can stick it in a variable and do stuff with it
  i = i - 4         # now I want the line 4 lines before the initial target line
  print lines[i]    # doesn't work, gives error: TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If anyone knows how to do this the help would be appreciated!

Comment: how are you creating lines? You can also just use `lines[i-4]`

Comment: lines = the terminal output of a process that I call. I tried your suggestion but got the same error.

Comment: I did not mean it would work, I mean adding to the answer below that you don't need to use `i = i - 4 ` you can just use `lines[i-4]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a list to have random access:

```
lines = list(lines)

# your code
```

A generator just feeds you items one at a time, and has no concept of "indexing", unlike a list.

Alternatively, if your file is very large and putting all of the lines into a list would be too expensive, you could extract 4 items at a time from the generator. That way, you would have access to the line four lines before your target line should you find it. You'd have to do some bookkeeping to make sure that you don't skip over any lines.

Answer (score 1):

Agree about the list(lines) answer.  Simplest solution.

If however your input file is too large and you want to stick to a generator, a collections.deque should work to keep the last 4 lines around in case you have a hit.  Older rows will be discarded as you go.

```
from collections import deque

mybuffer = deque(maxlen=4)

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
   mybuffer.append(line)
   #...some more of your code...
   if target in line:
       line_4_lines_before = mybuffer[0]
       line_3_lines_before = mybuffer[1]
```